# The minimum number of days required for finding the criminal

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

**Problem:** Every day, the detective can invite one or more of $80$ people, including a criminal and a witness to the crime, to the office and talk to them about the case. The detective knows that if there is the witness among those invited but the criminal is not in the group, the witness will say who the criminal is. In at least how many days can the detective following this method find the criminal with certainty?

**My Attempt for The Solution:**
The detective can definitively find the criminal in $80$ days. He calls one person every day, and in the worst case, the witness may end up at the bottom of the list of testifiers.

So what would happen if we formed $40$ groups of $2$ each? Let  $\{ a_1, b_1\}, \{ a_2, b_2\}, \dots , \{ a_{40}, b_{40}\}$ be the groups. It takes $40$ days to investigate them. If no results can be obtained from these groups, it means that the witness and the criminal are in the same group. Let's create groups in a different way: $ \{ a_1, a_2\},  \{ a_3, a_4\}, \dots  ,\{ a_{39}, a_{40}\}, \{ b_1, b_2\},  \{ b_3, b_4\}, \dots  ,\{ b_{39}, b_{40}\}$. Now the criminal and the witness are in different groups. The investigating of these groups also takes $40$ days. Again, $40+40=80$ days are needed.

Can the criminal be identified in fewer days? Maybe more successful results can be obtained with different grouping methods, I am not sure. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I can do it in 18 days, nine at a time. Don't know what would be the best.

Comment: Hint on the $18$-day answer: arrange the $80$ into a $9\times 9$ square. The witness and criminal can't both be in the same row and the same column. (If the detective has to invite the same number of people every day, it might be a little harder.)

Comment: In your example, instead of taking new $40$ groups of the form $\{ b_1, b_2\},  \{ b_3, b_4\}, \dots  ,\{ b_{39}, b_{40}\}$, you can make two groups of the form $\{a_1, a_3, a_5, \dots a_{39}\}$ and $\{a_2, a_4, a_6, \dots a_{40}\}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , I don't know the concept affine plane on a finite field. On the other hand, I can write an example of your answer about $18$ days: For the groups $\{ a_1, a_2, \dots , a_9\}, \{ a_{10}, a_{11}, \dots , a_{18}\}, \dots , \{ a_{73}, a_{74}, \dots , a_{80}\}$. We need $9$ days. After we can re-group the people $\{ a_1, a_{10}, \dots , a_{73}\}, \{ a_{2}, a_{11}, \dots , a_{74}\}, \dots ,  \{ a_{8}, a_{17}, \dots , a_{80}\}, \{ a_{9}, a_{18}, \dots , a_{72}\}$. We need $9$ days. We get $9+9=18$ days. Thank you for giving me the idea.

Comment: @scarface yeah, I quickly deleted my affine space comment and gave an easier version of my $18$ day answer.

Comment: Ignore my claim of $7$ days. I can do it in $14$ days. Not sure if that is best.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think its the best as well, and the proof can be given using the adversary argument. I am thinking about it right now and will edit my answer to include that

Comment: Okay, I can do it in $9$ days, and I think you can't do it in fewer days. Hint: $\binom{9}{\lfloor 9/2\rfloor}>80.$

Comment: @EnEm Which is best, $7$ (my wrong answer) or $14?$ I can do better than $14.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S_1,S_2,\dots,S_n$ be your daily selected people.

Then for each person $i,$ let $T_i=\{j\mid i\in S_j\}.$ That is $T_i$ is the list of days when person $i$ is invited.

Now, given $i_1\neq i_2,$ if $T_{i_1}\subseteq T_{i_2},$ you'd invite person $i_2$ every day you invited person $i_1.$ So you wouldn't have solved the problem when $i_1$ was the witness and $i_2$ is the criminal

So to have a solution, the $T_i$ must be an antichain on the set of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$ But by [Sperner's theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem?wprov=sfti1) the largest such antichain is of size $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}.$

So you can't do it in fewer than $9$ days since $\binom94\geq 80>\binom84.$

But we can do the above in reverse, to get an answer from an antichain of $80$ elements.

Let $\mathcal U=\mathcal U_{9,4}$ be the set of subsets of $\{1,\dots,9\}$ of size $4.$ It is an antichain and $|\mathcal U|>80,$ For each of $j=1,\dots,80$  pick a distinct $T_j\in \mathcal U.$ Then $T_1,\dots,T_{80}$ is an antichain.

Then let $S_i=\{j\mid i\in T_j\},$ $i=1,\dots,9.$

Show that $S_1,\dots, S_9$ works.

Turns out, since $\binom93=84>80,$ we can use $\mathcal U_{9,3}$ instead. We just need an antichain of size $80.$ This does not reduce the total number of days, but each person only has to come in three days, rather than four.

In general, for a population of $N$ people, the number of days is the smallest $n$ such that $\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\geq N.$

---

For example, with $10$ people, you have $n=5$ and the $$(T_i)_{i=1}^{10}=12,13,14,15,23,24,25,34,35,45$$ and:
$$\begin{align}  S_1&=\{1,2,3,4\}\\
S_2&=\{1,5,6,7\}\\
S_3&=\{2,5,8,9\}\\
S_4&=\{3,6,8,10\}\\
S_5&=\{4,7,9,10\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Really cute answer. I don't get to see Sperner's theorem used that much.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel In my $\sim 4000$ answers here, I've used it three times.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews An ingenious and brilliant solution that I need to review again!